# Catch exception while getting data from text box

Tags: c#, try-catch

User needs to insert a few numbers in text box, split by ','. Now, I want to throw an exception if he does something wrong (for example, if he writes 1;2,3).

```
string perm = this.tbxPerm.Text;
string[] elPerm = this.perm.Split(',');
```

Please suggest me how to use the try catch blocks here.

Comment: Why use `Try ... Catch` blocks? Just test for valid input and reject it if it doesn't meet your criteria..

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: OK John, I'll be more carefull next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than throwing exceptions when you hit bad data you can just validate it and reject it if it doesn't meet your critiera..  Consider the below function for detecting invalid characters in a string.

```
    public bool CheckString(string str)
    {
            char[] badChars = new char[] { '#', '$', '!', '@', '%', '_', ';' }; 

            foreach (char bad in badChars)
            {
                if (str.Contains(bad))
                    return false;
            }

            return true;
    }
```

Usage could be something like:

```
        string perm = this.tbxPerm.Text

           if (!CheckString(perm))
           { 
           System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(perm + " is invalid, please try again");
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using linq:

```
string perm = this.tbxPerm.Text;

if(perm.Any(c=> !char.IsDigit(c) && c != ','))
   throw new Exception("Wrong input");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `TryParse()` function to check wether conversion is working or not.
`TryParse()` function will return `true` if the conversion is successfull otherwise return `false`

```
            string perm = this.tbxPerm.Text;
            string[] elPerm = perm.Split(',');
            int num;
            for (int i = 0; i < elPerm.Length; i++)
            {
                if(!int.TryParse(elPerm[i],out num))
                throw new Exception("Invalid Data Found");
            }
```